# File comparison / highlighting differences in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, file, svn, merge, comparison

We need to add a feature in our application which will allow user to compare two versions of files with differences highlighted. This feature has to similar to **SVN**. Is there any utility/API that we can use to achieve this functionality?

Comment: If you're planning to use SVN to manage versioning of the files, then [ViewVC](http://www.viewvc.org/) might be worth looking at.

Comment: Can we use ViewVC in an asp.net application ?

Comment: I don't think it can be done directly. You will probably have to have your ASP.NET application "hand off" the diff viewing to ViewVC through a link that the former would construct and request.

Answer (score 0):

Our tool ECMerge is used by several websites that way to produce diff reports (typically by running the command line and applying your own XSLT or scripting the output directly as ECMerge uses Javascript 3rd edition as its scripting language and differences lists are available to scripting).
There is also an ActiveX which can be called directly from C#.